# How to format exception output in springboot with ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> and Interceptor?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, interceptor, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I format my springboot application output to json even when exception happens.

format is as follows:

```
{
"result": null,
"code": "-1",
"msg": "Exception happen"
}
```

It's ok when the code only with a ResponseBodyAdvice, main code is :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public <T> GlobalResponse<T> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
    return GlobalResponse.fail("Exception happen");
}
```

But when I add a Interceptor like the code below, the application always call the path "/error", return a error page, not the json data.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class InterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

@Override
protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new TestInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/error");
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
```

the TestInterceptor is a token validation interceptor.

Now I add a controller include path "/error" to deal with that, but I want to know if there is a better and natural way to solve this.